# Distance between multisets of integers

Tags: geometry, integers

If you have two multisets of integers $X$ and $Y$ both of size $n$, I define a matching to be a multiset of pairs with one integer from $X$ and one from $Y$  in each pair.  A matching must have exactly $n$ pairs and each integer from $X$ (resp $Y$) can only be used once.  In other words we are making a perfect bipartite matching of the elements of $X$ and $Y$.

The weight of a pair is the absolute difference between the two integers. I define the distance between $X$ and $Y$ as the minimum total weight of any matching.

Is there a simple and fast way to compute the distance between any two such $X$ and $Y$? It is tempting just to pair each integer in $X$ with the nearest value in $Y$ that has not already been taken but I am not sure this is always optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to sort $X$ and $Y$, then match the largest element of $X$ with the largest of $Y$ and continue down the line.  As an example, let $X=\{5,10\}, Y=\{1,6\}$.  If you match $5$ and $6$ because they are close the distance is $10$.  If you match $10$ and $6$ the distance is $8$.

Comment: That's a great counter example. Can you prove your method is optimal (or even no worse than my algorithm)?

Comment: I believe you can by induction.  Once you have sorted $X$ and $Y$ start with the smallest element of each.  There is only one matching, so it is the best.  Now add in the next element and show that matching the two new ones is at least as good as crossing over.  Keep going in pairs that way.  I haven't written it up, so it might not work out.  The secret to my example is that you would like all the differences to be in the same direction.  When you make a swap that changes that, you lose.

Comment: A full answer is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95546/the-sum-of-differences-between-two-data-sets-is-minimized-when-both-are-ordered